# Why is @sql in this case here a nvarchar(max) variable and how does this affect the statement? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

Regarding this code:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

...

BEGIN TRANSACTION loadTempWorkingTime;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##tempWorkingTime;

    SET @query = 'SELECT 
                    u_iv_1,
                    personnel_number,
                    date,
                    department_name,
                    alran_department_id,
                    CONVERT(begin_time, CHAR) AS begin_time,
                    CONVERT(end_time, CHAR) AS end_time,
                    break,
                    ordinary_hours,
                    total_working_time,
                    paid_nonworking_time,
                    workday,
                    Approved_by_user,
                    Approved_by_admin,
                    Approved_by_user_1,
                    working_time_total_balance,
                    holiday,
                    holiday_balance,
                    LOGA_AS_anpassung
                FROM pm_altran.altran_pm_working_time_overview 
                WHERE Date BETWEEN "' + CAST(@firstDayToConsider AS VARCHAR(10)) + '" AND "' + CAST(@lastDayToConsider AS VARCHAR(10)) + '" 
                    AND active=1 AND personnel_number<>""''';
        SET @sql = N'select * into ##tempWorkingTime
                    from OPENQUERY(
                            [SRV_Timetac],''';
        SET @sql = @sql + @query + ')';
        EXEC (@sql);
        COMMIT TRANSACTION loadTempWorkingTime;
```

Especially this portion:

```
SET @sql = N'select * into ##tempWorkingTime
                    from OPENQUERY(
                            [SRV_Timetac],''';
        SET @sql = @sql + @query + ')';
```

Context:

I am currently starting to get into SQL in general and I trying to find out, which procedure calls which and so on. I was looking for the EXEC statements to get a closer view, but I've stumbled upon this statement now quite often and I cant really seem to wrap my hear around this.

So it looks like `@sql` is a temporary table.

Now we are selecting data from from pm_altran.altran_pm_working_time_overview 
and inserting it into `@sql`.

Am I right here?

Especially at this line:

```
SET @sql = N'select * into ##tempWorkingTime
```

This "N'select" really bothers me.

If you guys could explain a little more what is going on here, i'd be very, very happy :)

Thank you friends!

Comment: If you can take a look at **[`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)** arguments, you will see that _[ @stmt= ] statement Is a Unicode string that contains a Transact-SQL statement or batch. @stmt must be either a Unicode constant or a Unicode variable_ So it **should be** NVARCHAR. If you need to deal with unicode charecters in your query it will be represented as `?`. So avoid this and use the right datatype.

Comment: The first parameter `sp_executesql` is an `nvarchar(MAX)`. *If* you therefore had non-Ascii characters in your object definitions, and were creating a dynamic statement with a `varchar`, then those characters would be implicitly changed to a `?`. If you then put those values into a `nvarchar(MAX)`, your statement would fail. it is therefore always best to ensure you correct define your dynamic statements as an `nvarchar` and ensure you define your string literals as one too (but using the `N` prefix).

Comment: Also, you should be parametrising the clause `Date BETWEEN "' + CAST(@firstDayToConsider AS VARCHAR(10)) + '" AND "' + CAST(@lastDayToConsider AS VARCHAR(10)) + '"`, not injecting the values into the statement. That also means you need to stop using `EXEC (@SQL)` and  use `sp_executesql` (which you should be doing anyway). [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: No, `@Sql` is not a temporary table. It's not a table at all, it's a string. Specifically, a Unicode string with a maximum length of two Gigabytes

Comment: Wait, i'm confused, are `@firstDayToConsider` and `@lastDayToConsider` a column? They're wrapped by double quotes (`"`) in the dynamic statement, which means that you're defining them as a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@sql` is not a temporary table, it is just a variable that holds an `nvarchar(max)` value.  This data type is for unicode strings and the `max` signifies that there is no (strictly speaking an inordinately high) limit to the amount of text that it can hold.  This does have consequences compared to specifying a numeric limit (such as `nvarchar(500)`), but those are details for another time.

The statement you highlight:

```
SET @sql = N'select * into ##tempWorkingTime
                    from OPENQUERY(
                            [SRV_Timetac],''';
        SET @sql = @sql + @query + ')';
```

is simply building up an SQL statement within the `@sql` variable, by concatenating the text held in both `@sql` and `@query` and then a closing parenthesis.  The result of this concatenation is saved back to the `@sql` variable, overwriting the previous value.  The `N'` prefix tells SQL Server that the following text will be unicode.

Once the full SQL statement has been built and stored in the `@sql` variable, it is executed against the database via the `EXEC(@sql)` at the end of your script.

This making up of a SQL script on the fly and then executing it is known as *Dynamic SQL*, because the contents of the statement you are executing can change.

Comment: Nitpicking: max length of `nvarchar(max)` is documented as 2GB. A 2GB string in UTF-16 is very long, but not infinite.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  Hence the clarification *there is no (strictly speaking an inordinately high) limit*

Comment: Yeah, I got that, Hence the "Nitpicking:" :-)

Comment: fantastic explanation. you sir done me a great deed